# Novel read online.about 2018. Prophecy a leader will gain a son. Adopts a lizardlike boy of another race

Tags: story-identification, novel

I think the father is the chief of a nomadic tribe. There is a prophecy he will soon gain a son.His wife is pregnant but the child is stillborn.Maybe both mother and child die. He adopts a lizardlike boy of another race.

They travel around trading.They are a happy family.
I read it online about 2018
I think it was an actual novel, not fanfic.
The is an elderly lady in the tribe who is a healer.